# Is there an effective speech recognition application for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, open-source, speech-recognition

I'm looking for something that works as well as the Dragon NaturallySpeaking, Windows Speech Recognition or MacSpeech Dictate - except for Ubuntu. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: [Is there any decent speech recognition software for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256138/16704)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux)*:

> There is currently no open-source
>   equivalent of proprietary speech
>   recognition software (e.g. Nuance's
>   Dragon NaturallySpeaking or Windows
>   Speech Recognition) for GNU/Linux.
>   However, there are several incomplete,
>   open-source projects and solutions
>   that could be used to attain some
>   elements of speech recognition in the
>   free operating system. It is also
>   possible to use Windows speech
>   recognition software under GNU/Linux.

I think it would be possibly (and fairly easy) to use Dragon NaturallySpeaking in a virtualized Windows environment by running Windows in something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org).

*Depending on how much faith you put into Wikipedia articles

Comment: That's what many Linux folks who wants to use voice recognition do, e.g. http://pyvideo.org/video/1735/using-python-to-code-by-voice

Answer (score 3):

I know that this questions is "old", but I can confirm that Dragon runs fine (although a little "slow") within recent versions of Wine.

Note that what doesn't work is the ability to "dictate anyware" as "non-wine" windows are not recognized as being "dictable" fields.  But if you dictate inside the DragonPad, then everything works perfectly.

Cheers!

Comment: WineHQ user feedback on DNS with Wine: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2077

Answer (score 1):

In addition to running Dragon NaturallySpeaking in a Windows VM host and having your Linux distro as guest, there [exist](http://www.linux.com/news/embedded-mobile/mobile-linux/711479-palaver-taps-googles-voice-technology-for-linux-speech-recognition/) some Linux programs tapping Google's voice technology but I haven't tried it myself. I wonder how long Google will authorize this, although it's a nice way to get more training data.